# Material Ui XGrid filterMode is not working in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I have a React component using XGrid. The filtering option for the DateTime type is working fine in the dev environment but it is not working in staging (production) environment. So, I have tried to add `filterMode: "server"` and/or `onFilterModelChange={onFilterChange}`. It didnt work...

I followed the [Material-UI documentation on server-side filtering](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/).

Please find the code below:

```
export default function DeviceList() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(50);
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const historyList = useSelector(
    (state) => state.reducer.data || []
  );

  const historyListTotal = useSelector(
    (state) => state.reducer.total
  );

  const onFilterChange = React.useCallback((params) => {
    setFilterValue(params.filterModel.items[0].value);
    console.log("params", params.filterModel.items[0].value);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(readDevices(`/history`, page + 1, pageSize));
  }, [dispatch, page, pageSize, filterValue]);

  const fetchLoader = () => {
    dispatch(showLoader());
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(hideLoader());
    }, 750);
  };

  const onHandlePageChange = (param) => {
    setPage(param.page);
  };

  const onHandlePageSizeChange = (param) => {
    setPageSize(param.pageSize);
    setPage(0);
  };

  let rows = historyList.map((obj, index) => {
    return (rows = {
      id: index + 1,
      ID: obj.device_mrid,
      "Communication Status": obj.device_status,
      "Last Reading": obj.status_updated_time,
    });
  });

  const columns = [
    {
      field: "ID",
      flex: 1,
    },
    {
      field: "Communication Status",
      flex: 1,
    },
    {
      field: "Last Reading",
      flex: 1,
      type: "dateTime",
      // filterMode: "server",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>      
      <div style={{ height: "90%", width: "100%" }}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={MaterialTheme}>
          <XGrid
            pageSize={pageSize}
            page={page}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
            rowCount={historyListTotal}
            onPageChange={onHandlePageChange}
            onPageSizeChange={onHandlePageSizeChange}
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            paginationMode="server"
            pagination={true}
            //Server-side filtering
            filterMode="server"
            onFilterModelChange={onFilterChange}
            //           
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: 1. not sure if it's a problem, but in the example they are providing in the tutorial, onFilterChange uses filterModel directly and not via params like in the code you provided. I think it's worth a shot calling it directly.
2 . you pass the filterValue in the dependency list of the useEffect, but do you actually use it in  readDevices?
3. Where do you keep the results that are resolved from readDevices?
4. Could you share the full code in codesandbox.io, it would be much easier to help

Comment: Please do not use a stack snippet unless it actually adds something to the post (e.g. HTML, JS that logs something). Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.